# Error compiling a C program

Tags: c, windows, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm studying C at school, we had to create a program that managesa vector of music albums, I tried do compile but I have this error and i Can't find informations about that, the compiler error is:
"in get_parm_info, at c-decl.c:4637".

What should I do?

It's only a message.

The code is too long to fit there, but it has no other errors other than that.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STR 50
#define MAX_CANZONI 20
#define ALBUM_SIZE 44
struct t_canzone { //54 bytes   
    char titolo[MAX_STR];
    int durata; //In secondi
};
struct t_autore { //104 bytes
    char nome[MAX_STR];
    char cognome[MAX_STR];  
    int eta;
};
struct t_album {
    struct t_autore autore; //104 bytes
    char titolo[MAX_STR];   //50 bytes
    int numCanzoni;         //4 bytes
    struct t_canzone canzoni[MAX_CANZONI]; //1080 bytes
};    

void inizializzazione(struct t_album album);
void stampacompleta(struct t_album album);
void stampaalbum(struct t_album album,char nome[]);
void cercacanzone(struct t_album album, char nome[]);
void modificaalbum(struct t_album album, char nome[]);
void aggiungicanzone(struct t_album album, char nome[]);
void ordinamento(struct t_album album,void confronto(struct t_album,int,int);
void crescente(struct t_album album,int i,int z);
void decrescente(struct t_album album,int i,int z);
void titlesort(struct t_album album,int i,int z);
void namesort(struct t_album album,int i,int z);

void crescente(struct t_album album,int i,int z){
    struct t_album supporto;
    if(album[i].numCanzoni>album[z].numCanzoni)
    {
        supporto=album[i];
        album[i]=album[z];
        album[z]=supporto;
    }
}

void decrescente(struct t_album album,int i,int z){
    struct t_album supporto;
    if(album[i].numCanzoni<album[z].numCanzoni)
    {
        supporto=album[i];
        album[i]=album[z];
        album[z]=supporto;
    }
}

void titlesort(struct t_album album,int i,int z){
    if(strncmp(album[i].titolo,album[z].titolo)>0)
    {
        supporto=album[i];
        album[i]=album[z];
        album[z]=supporto;
    }
}

void namesort(struct t_album album,int i,int z){
    if(strncmp(album[i].autore.nome,album[z].autore.nome)>0)
    {
        supporto=album[i];
        album[i]=album[z];
        album[z]=supporto;
    }
    else if(strncmp(album[i].autore.nome,album[z].autore.nome)==0)
    {
        if(strncmp(album[i].autore.cognome,album[z].autore.cognome)>0)
        {
            supporto=album[i];
            album[i]=album[z];
            album[z]=supporto;
        }
    }
}  



void ordinamento(struct t_album album,void confronto(struct t_album,int,int){
    int i,z;
    for(i=0;i<ALBUM_SIZE-1;i++)
    {
        for(z=i+1;z<ALBUM_SIZE;z++)
        {
            confronto(album[],i,z);
        }
    }
}
```

---

[update from comment:]

The complete "error" message is:

```
Compiler: Default compiler Executing gcc.exe... gcc.exe "C:\Users\lavpreet\Desktop\canzone.c" -o "C:\Users\lavpreet\Desktop\canzone.exe" -g3 -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include" -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" -g3 C:\Users\lavpreet\Desktop\canzone.c:35: internal compiler error: in get_parm_info, at c-decl.c:4637 
Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropriate. See <URL:http://www.mingw.org/bugs.shtml> for instructions. Execution terminated
```

Comment: Only show *relevant* code to the problem. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: ...and the *whole* error message.

Comment: No, I don't know how to do it, but the compile log says this:

`Compiler: Default compiler
Executing  gcc.exe...
gcc.exe "C:\Users\lavpreet\Desktop\canzone.c" -o "C:\Users\lavpreet\Desktop\canzone.exe"   -g3  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" -g3 
C:\Users\lavpreet\Desktop\canzone.c:35: internal compiler error: in get_parm_info, at c-decl.c:4637
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <URL:http://www.mingw.org/bugs.shtml> for instructions.

Execution terminated`

Comment: That is a fragment of the error message (telling where the compiler *thinks* the error is.  What might be useful in your case is to comment out small sections of your code till it compiles, and then look look at the last bit your commented out.  The real error probably lurks there.

Comment: Congratulations: you found a compiler bug. For a beginner, that's impressive. The error message tells you what to do. There's no reason to ask any questions on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Dare to show the 1st, lets say 40, lines of `canzone.c`?

Comment: if you add the complete message to the question you maybe still wont get an answer, but the up/downvote ratio may improve a bit

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Nice. The conventional wisdom is that the compiler is always right and you are always wrong, even if you think the compiler may be at fault. I've never seen a case of the compiler actually admitting to being wrong.

Comment: @jforberg: I did ;-) but to provoke this I had to run a dozen instances of GCC in parallel against some hundred of thousands to not say against millions of source lines.

Comment: @jforberg - rare, but happens. Had a few, in the years past. Reported them, and had them fixed.

Comment: What does `gcc --version` tell you?

Comment: posted some code now,

Comment: Is this `void ordinamento(struct t_album album,void confronto(struct t_album,int,int);` a copypasta mistake?

Comment: Nope, don't know if it's helpful but this is the first time i use 'pointer to functions'

Comment: Fix this: `void ordinamento(struct t_album album,void confronto(struct t_album,int,int);` as it definitely makes no sense. And retry.

Comment: Ok i will try, probably i haven't understood the syntax of functions pointer

Comment: This line at the minimum misses a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Perhaps you want:  `void ordinamento(struct t_album album,void (*confronto)(struct t_album,int,int));` Here `confronto` would be the 2nd parameter to `ordinamento` and a pointer to a function.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks a lot. Now it shows me more errors, but they are fixable. thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
void ordinamento(      struct t_album album, void confronto(struct t_album, int, int);
```

is missing a trailing `)`

also this line:

```
void ordinamento(struct t_album album,void confronto(struct t_album,int,int){
```

is missing a trailing `)`

Comment: when you fix the above two syntax errors, Then a bunch of other warnings and errors will be displayed by the compiler.  All those other warnings and errors also need to be fixed.

Comment: Yes, it worked thanks a lot. Now I will fix the other mistakes